# Mongodb gather all Collection Information for given Collection

Tags: mongodb, collections

Hi I'm getting through the basics of mongodb and am trying to retrive all of the columns and information from mongodb via a db query.

I currently have a query (`'; return ''+db.getCollectionNames().length == '3` that returns all of the information for a `collection` named `london_garages`

I want to return data from the following 2 other db collections: "garages", "system"

How can I do so?

Thank you

Comment: What "columns and information"? `getCollectionNames()` is actually returning all of the collections in the database. It optionally takes a filter, if that is what you are asking?

Comment: How can I view a specific collection contents? e.g. getCollectionNames('system') in pseudocode.

Comment: @Ashish - this doesnt specify the actual collection though

Comment: so `db.mycollection.find({}) ?

Comment: So my original command would look like? `'; return ''+System.find({})` to get all the content of collection `system` ?

Comment: @Ashish this doesnt seem to show any content from `System` table